# Error 1146: Table '********.ip_login_log' doesn't exist after updating InvoicePlane to 1.6.0

Tags: php, mariadb, invoiceplane

I thoroughly followed the [upgrade instructions to upgrade InvoicePlane 1.5.1 to 1.6.0](https://wiki.invoiceplane.com/en/1.6/getting-started/updating-ip) so I can upgrade my PHP version from 7.1 to 8.1.

After upgrading, InvoicePlane will show me the login screen as expected, but trying to login results in

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table '********.ip_login_log' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM `ip_login_log` WHERE `login_name` = '************'

Filename: modules/sessions/controllers/Sessions.php
```

Someone else also [reported this problem on the InvoicePlane support forums](https://community.invoiceplane.com/t/topic/10008/5).

Apparently the new version uses a table the previous version does not have.

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it:

1. Open `ipconfig.php` in the root folder.
2. In line 14, change

   ```
   DISABLE_SETUP=true
   ```

   to

   ```
   DISABLE_SETUP=false
   ```
3. Change line 48 from

   ```
   SETUP_COMPLETED=true
   ```

   to

   ```
   SETUP_COMPLETED=false
   ```
4. Point your browser to your InvoicePlane installation and you should now follow the on screen instructions to complete the setup process.
5. **Important!** After successfully logging in, remember to revert the changes you made in the previous steps 2. and 3.